# What happens if 2 truly omnipotent beings (like God) fight each other to the death?

Tags: theology

Omnipotence is the ability to anything, be invincible, and immortal/unkillable. But what happens if there are 2 omnipotent beings?

There are 2 answers that I have heard, and both are not satisfactory: the omnipotence will cancel itself out, and nothing happens, or both beings will be destroyed. If the omnipotence is cancelled out, and if omnipotence can do anything, the couldn't it just uncancel itself? If both of them die, can't they just bring themselves back to life?

As you can see, God fighting God leads to paradoxes, but making the assumption that these 2 omnipotent beings can meet (saying the fight never happens is not giving the out come of said fight) for the purpose of this discussion, what would be the outcome and deciding factor?

Comment: If we produce a contradiction, this means that the set of premises is inconsistent, i.e. not all the premises can be TRUE. Maybe Gods are not omnipotent, maybe there are not two omnipotent Gods, maybe tehre are no Gods at all...

Comment: But, for example, if God splits himself in 2, then how do the halves fight?

Comment: Per the usual definition of 'omnipotent' there could not be 2 such beings, so the question is a contradiction. This is another reason why omnipotence as usually glossed is a silly concept that makes no sense (along with standard can God make a meal too big for him to lift etc. questions). Personally, this is why I think that the usual way of discussing omnipotence is daft; it also doesn't form any part of the commitments of any religion I know of...

Comment: @RolloBurgess So, then, there is no God or Omnipotent being?

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/omnipotence/ the first section talks about two or more omnipotent beings.

Comment: @return So then there is no omnipotence?

Comment: @return if there are 2, neither are omnipotent.

Comment: Yes, this is like asking what shape a square circle would have. [What happens when an unstoppable force meets an immovable object?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irresistible_force_paradox) is in the same incoherent category.

Comment: the result will be made into a video game to entertain adolescents of all ages.

Comment: @mikY - I think that the various silly paradoxes associated with the idea of omnipotence are indeed indicators that the way the word is often used doesn't refer to anything (it is self-contradictory!). From a theistic perspective this has never caused me any concern; omnipotent/pantokrator type epithets, literally meaning 'all powerful', just say that God is very very powerful, vastly more so than any other being. No paradoxes, done.

Answer (score 1):

There are a series of [Omnipotence Paradoxes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipotence_paradox), and the theology addressed to those can help investigate what omnipotence has meant within different traditions.

In Zoroastrianism, Ahura Mazda the lord of wisdom, represents spiritual principles and transcendent ideas, of life-force, which they link to fire. While his adversary Ahriman  is the lord of worldly things who made the mundane world and the temptations in it away from transcendent ideas.

> "In ancient Zoroastrian eschatology, a 3,000-year struggle between good
> and evil will be fought, punctuated by evil's final assault. During
> the final assault, the sun and moon will darken and humankind will
> lose its reverence for religion, family, and elders. The world will
> fall into winter, and Angra Mainyu's most fearsome miscreant, Azi
> Dahaka, will break free and terrorize the world.
>
> According to legend, the final savior of the world, known as the
> Saoshyant, will be born to a virgin impregnated by the seed of
> Zoroaster while bathing in a lake. The Saoshyant will raise the
> dead—including those in all afterworlds—for final judgment, returning
> the wicked to hell to be purged of bodily sin. Next, all will wade
> through a river of molten metal in which the righteous will not burn
> but through which the impure will be completely purified. The forces
> of good will ultimately triumph over evil, rendering it forever
> impotent but not destroyed. The Saoshyant and Ahura Mazda will offer a
> bull as a final sacrifice for all time and all humans will become
> immortal. Mountains will again flatten and valleys will rise; the
> House of Song will descend to the moon, and the earth will rise to
> meet them both. Humanity will require two judgments because there
> are as many aspects to our being: spiritual (menog) and physical
> (getig). Thus, Zoroastrianism can be said to be a universalist
> religion with respect to salvation in that all souls are redeemed at
> the final judgement." - from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrianism#Eschatology:_Renovation_and_judgment)

I guess this is slightly cheating, because they considered Ahura Mazda to be more powerful. Possibly there is an analogy to politics, where it has been common to feel someone must have the highest authority, and take final responsibility as such for how things are.

Even in polytheist traditions there have usually been monistic interpretations, that sees all beings as aspects or manifestations of one Creator or Divine Reality. Similarly, angels demons & the devil have been interpreted by Christian theologians as modes of action of one being, in order to understand it as monotheistic.

I'd describe the idea of the various superlatives of monotheistic god, as arising from the fusion of Hellenic ideas into Jewish thought, found in Christianity, especially resulting from the impact of Plato. In Islam and Judaism, it is kept very clear and explicit that the deity is beyond our ability to conceptualise.